# My save data to MongoDB not functioning, is it because my searching is wrong?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make a comparison function. If the value that I search is not exist, the new value will be save to the database. But all I get is 0 new data found. So the system decides to not save the data. Is my searching wrong?

This is my code:

```
    var count = 0;
for (var t = 1; t < 151; t++) {

    var searching = JobsSchema.find({ jobName: name[t], company: company[t] })

    if (searching == null) {

        count = count + 1;

        var newJobs = new JobsSchema({
            "jobName": name[t],
            "country": country[t],
            "company": company[t],
            "jobType": type[t],
            "salary": salary[t],
            "skills": skills[t],
            "jobDesc": desc[t],
            "jobReq": req[t],
            "jobResponsibility": resp[t],
            "industry": industry[t],

        })

        newJobs.save(function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
    }
}

console.log(count + " new data found.");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `await` your `find` function.
Also, change it to `findOne` to return a single instance of the `JobsSchema` and `await` the `save` call as well.
Finally you will need to wrap the code into an `async` function:

```
const saveData = async () => {
  var count = 0;
  for (var t = 1; t < 151; t++) {
    var searching = await JobsSchema.findOne({
      jobName: name[t],
      company: company[t],
    });

    if (!searching) {
      count = count + 1;

      var newJobs = new JobsSchema({
        jobName: name[t],
        country: country[t],
        company: company[t],
        jobType: type[t],
        salary: salary[t],
        skills: skills[t],
        jobDesc: desc[t],
        jobReq: req[t],
        jobResponsibility: resp[t],
        industry: industry[t],
      });

      await newJobs.save();
    }
  }

  console.log(count + ' new data found.');
};

saveData();
```

Comment: It says my mongoclient is not connected?

Comment: You will need to include the code responsible for connecting to the database

Comment: The error appears because of mongoose.connection.close() . After I remove it, it can perform its task. But how or where do I put the connection close so I can close the app?

Comment: Putting it at the end of the `saveData` function should work.